# Add specific colorbar to each of 4 subplots colored as function of a third variable

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to create a figure composed b 4 subplots, each of them shows x,y colored as function of a third variable. Then i need to add a specific colorbar to each of the subplots and give the colorbar a title.
Here you find the final result made on Matlab:

!https://pasteboard.co/IeWZ03D.jpg

Here the code i used to generate the figure without the colorbar:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11,8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,2)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,3)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,4)
ax1.scatter(results['Qmean Loops (kW)'],results['eta daily (PCS)'],c=results['T ext (°C)'],s=14)
plt.tight_layout()
ax1.set_ylabel('\u03B7 Daily (-)',fontsize=14)
ax1.set_xlabel('Qmean Loops (kW)',fontsize=14)
ax2.scatter(results['Qmean Loops (kW)'],results['eta daily (PCS)'],c=results['T rit heat(°C)'],s=14)
plt.tight_layout()
ax2.set_ylabel('\u03B7 Daily (-)',fontsize=14)
ax2.set_xlabel('Qmean Loops (kW)',fontsize=14)
ax3.scatter(results['Qmean Loops (kW)'],results['eta daily (PCS)'],c=results['DT heat(°C)'],s=14)
plt.tight_layout()
ax3.set_ylabel('\u03B7 Daily (-)',fontsize=14)
ax3.set_xlabel('Qmean Loops (kW)',fontsize=14)
ax4.scatter(results['Qmean Loops (kW)'],results['eta daily (PCS)'],c=results['T mand heat(°C)'],s=14)
plt.tight_layout()
ax4.set_ylabel('\u03B7 Daily (-)',fontsize=14)
ax4.set_xlabel('Qmean Loops (kW)',fontsize=14)
fig.savefig("Daily Analysis\Efficiency vs P&T - S1.png", dpi=fig.dpi, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.close()
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You could try using `cmap` attribute of `scatter`. That way you are able to control the colors of each of the subplots as you like. Take a look to the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html). Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with the following code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11,8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,2)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,3)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,4)
sp1 = ax1.scatter(results['Qmean Loops (kW)'],results['eta daily (PCS)'],c =results['T ext (°C)'],s=14)
clb = plt.colorbar(sp1,ax=ax1)
clb.ax.set_title('T ext (°C)')
plt.tight_layout()
ax1.set_ylabel('\u03B7 Daily (-)',fontsize=14)
ax1.set_xlabel('Qmean Loops (kW)',fontsize=14)
sp2 = ax2.scatter(results['Qmean Loops (kW)'],results['eta daily (PCS)'],c=results['T return SH (°C)'],s=14)
clb = plt.colorbar(sp2,ax=ax2)
clb.ax.set_title('T return SH (°C)')
plt.tight_layout()
ax2.set_ylabel('\u03B7 Daily (-)',fontsize=14)
ax2.set_xlabel('Qmean Loops (kW)',fontsize=14)
sp3 = ax3.scatter(results['Qmean Loops (kW)'],results['eta daily (PCS)'],c=results['DTwater SH (°C)'],s=14)
clb = plt.colorbar(sp3,ax=ax3)
clb.ax.set_title('DTwater SH (°C)')
plt.tight_layout()
ax3.set_ylabel('\u03B7 Daily (-)',fontsize=14)
ax3.set_xlabel('Qmean Loops (kW)',fontsize=14)
sp4 = ax4.scatter(results['Qmean Loops (kW)'],results['eta daily (PCS)'],c=results['T forward SH (°C)'],s=14)
clb = plt.colorbar(sp4,ax=ax4)
clb.ax.set_title('T forward SH (°C)')
plt.tight_layout()
ax4.set_ylabel('\u03B7 Daily (-)',fontsize=14)
ax4.set_xlabel('Qmean Loops (kW)',fontsize=14)
fig.savefig("Daily Analysis\Efficiency vs P&T - S1.png", dpi=fig.dpi, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.close()
```

You can se the final results here:
https://pasteboard.co/IeYcaOB.png

Hope it can be useful!